# Corrupt info database format

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, raspberry-pi2, apt, dpkg

I have an issue while using *apt-get* to update or install something on my Raspberry pi 2 model B.

I get this error whenever I use *apt-get*:

```
dpkg: error: corrupt info database format file '/var/lib/dpkg/info/format'
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

I found in the Ubuntu forum that printing "1\n" to the format file would be the solution, and I tried that without succeeding.

When I print "1\n" to the format file and execute an update or install I get the following error:

```
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
files list file for package 'acl' is missing final newline
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Answer (score 0):

That smells like filesystem or disk corruption. You might need to fsck it, and see if other files have been damaged, or do a badblocks check or similar.